# Регулярное выражение для preg_replace которое срабатывает на обратный слеш ("\")

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

подскажите, пожалуйста, правильное регулярное выражение для preg_replace в PHP

слово формата "\\text\\" - пробую выражения типа

```
$patternItalic = "/\\{2}S+\\{2}/";
```

или так

```
$patternItalic = "/\\\\S+\\\\/";
```

Не работает.

Для формата **text** такие выражения работают

```
$patternBold "/\*{2}S+\*{2}/";
```

Comment: А суть задачи-то в чём заключается?

Comment: Если в тексте встречается слово в формате \\слово\\ -  заменить его на <i>слово</i>

Comment: \\ слеша это так обозначают один, и еще делают так \/

Comment: @Elena вы принципиально ни один свой вопрос не помечаете галкой?

Comment: `"\\{2}"` означает *найди `{2}`*. Вам надо использовать `"/(?:\\\\){2}\S+(?:\\\\){2}/"` или `"/(?:\\\\){2}[^\s\\\\]+(?:\\\\){2}/"`

Comment: @Эдуард не принципиально) галкой надо отмечать подходящий ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "\\text\\";

$text = preg_replace('~\\\\(\pL+)\\\\~', '<i>$1</i>', $text);

echo $text;
```

Результат:

```
<i>text</i>
```

---

[См. PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4895c3022909a9e07007501f3dc98e2accd52963)
[См. PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/s35Psk/1)

Comment: спасибо, работает!